# PHP foreach within foreach repeat data and not escaping loops

Tags: php, foreach, logic, controls, conditional-statements

Consider the below as a code,

```
<?php
foreach ( $alldata as $alldatakey=>$alldatavalue){
 foreach ( $alldatavalue as $neededdatakey=>$neededdatavalue){

  #conditions here

  foreach (){

  if(){
    $variable = $data1;
  }

  if(){
    $variable .= $data2;
  }

  if(){
    $variable .= $data3;
  }

  }


 }
  echo $variable;
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Sewer Connected, 
Sewer Connected, Septic, 
Sewer Connected, Septic, Septic, 

Sewer Connected, 
Sewer Connected, Septic, 
Sewer Connected, Septic, Septic, 

Sewer Connected, 
Sewer Connected, Septic, 
Sewer Connected, Septic, Septic, 

Sewer Connected, 
Sewer Connected, Septic, 
Sewer Connected, Septic, Septic,
```

The conditions for data1, data2 and data3 are correct. **Why the data is being printed repeatedly?**

Comment: unclosed foreach } and put unset($varibale); after the echo

Comment: Dave - I used this and it's almost working good but I am facing an issue like it it clearing the data and since it's in a loop, if empty I have assigned as 'NIL' for `$variable;` It is also clearing the NIL – without any data I cannot insert into a database.

Comment: the unset variable will do exactly that it clears the variable.  See your .= is concatting everything which is why you're getting duplicates on each itteration of the loop

Comment: I have a necessity of concatenating data because it's all a sub-category which are a result of one single category. Any idea why it's returning or having empty data for a array key because we are clearing data after insertion in db. so once again when foreach executes it should be containing newer data but it's clearing some value in array. How to avoid this issue?

Comment: Dave post it as an answer! I want to accept it! atleast post the `unset` idea as an answer.

Comment: I've posted it up for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unclosed `foreach }`

put `unset($varibale);` after the echo so your code looks something like this

```
<?php
foreach ( $alldata as $alldatakey=>$alldatavalue) {
 foreach ( $alldatavalue as $neededdatakey=>$neededdatavalue) {
  foreach () {
    //internal loop
      if() {
           $variable = $data1;
      }
      if() {
           $variable .= $data2;
      }
      if() {
           $variable .= $data3;
      }

  }
 }
  echo $variable;
  unset($variable);  // we unset it here so that we only each out the subcat blocks for that key cat not concat all subs and primaries
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you it was showing up like, would like to consider any answer to accept!

Answer (score 1):

Move your **`echo`** statement here

```
        }
        //echo $varibale;

    }
    echo $varibale;//Move here <-----

}
?>
```

Comment: It was there as you said above.

Comment: Try moving it outside of the `for` loop. I mean after the last brace.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write extreme out of all your loop

```
    <?php
    foreach ( $alldata as $alldatakey=>$alldatavalue){
     foreach ( $alldatavalue as $neededdatakey=>$neededdatavalue){

      #conditions here

      foreach (){

      if(){
        $varibale = $data1;
      }

      if(){
        $varibale .= $data2;
      }

      if(){
        $varibale .= $data3;
        break;
      }
      }
    if(!empty($data3)){
    break;
   }

     }
      echo $varibale;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why do you copy answers? This was already suggested in Shankar's answer below.

Comment: I can't since, I am inserting into data, I wanted one by one insert, so wanted it to be just above the first loop ends.

Comment: Amal - Neeraj's answer was 3minutes ahead of Shankar's. No fights or complaints. Be happy share knowledge. I appreciate you all!

Comment: @AmalMurali, LOL I don't know how OP calculated that. Mine says answered 25 mins ago and Neeraj's 14 mins ago.

Comment: @NeerajKumar: Really? You may want to take a look at the [timeline for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20375947/timeline). Shankar posted his answer 28 minutes ago and Neeraj 15 minutes ago -- which means there is a difference of ~13 minutes between both the posting.

Comment: Why you guys are fighting for a simple thing just forget it. :)

Comment: @NeerajKumar, This isn't a fight btw. Amal just made a point.